# How to change background-color of a header according to the div offsetHeight?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the color of my header when I go through a div other than the original but I'm not getting it. How to add another function to window.addEventListener? Is that the way?

[Example](https://codepen.io/maba/pen/BXzNpb?editors=1010)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var height = document.getElementById('section-2').offsetHeight;

function logoChanger() {
  if(this.scrollY > height) {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.add('white');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('white');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', logoChanger);
```

Comment: Welcome. Your question is not clear -- it looks to me like your code is already correct and already working. What is it you're hoping to do with it that it does not already do?

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dxXGXM

Comment: Are you wanting to change the color of the div each time you scroll into another div, or only the first time? Is that what isn't working in your Codepen?

Comment: Thanks @Kyle, That's the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `offsetHeight`, use `offsetTop` instead. In your example `Section-1` and `Section-2` has similar height so you are not facing anything.. if you have `Section-2` height more/less than the `Section-1` than it will not work as expected...

In below both example, I have reduced the height of `#Section-2` element to `500px` instead of `1000px`.

See [this](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/aeZdBo) or see the Snippet below:

```js
var height = document.getElementById('section-2').offsetHeight;

function logoChanger() {
  if(this.scrollY > height) {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.add('white');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('white');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', logoChanger);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 24px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  
}

  #header.white {
    background: tomato;
  }
#section-1 {
  background: #fff;
  height: 1000px;
}

#section-2 {
  background: #000;
  height: 500px;
}

#section-3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <p>(Section-2 height=500px and checking with <strong>offsetHeight</strong>)</p>
</header>

<div id="section-1">
  Section 1
</div>

<div id="section-2">
  Section 2
</div>

<div id="section-3">
  Section 3
</div>
```

You should use `offsetTop` to make the condition..

See [this](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/GVqoNm) or see the Snippet below:

```js
var height = document.getElementById('section-2').offsetTop;

function logoChanger() {
  if(this.scrollY > height) {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.add('white');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('header').classList.remove('white');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', logoChanger);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 24px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  
}

#header.white {
    background: tomato;
  }
#section-1 {
  background: #fff;
  height: 1000px;
}

#section-2 {
  background: #000;
  height: 500px;
}

#section-3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <p>(Section-2 height=500px and checking with <strong>offsetTop</strong>)</p>
</header>

<div id="section-1">
  Section 1
</div>

<div id="section-2">
  Section 2
</div>

<div id="section-3">
  Section 3
</div>
```